# Cannot export data from excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel, export, xsd

I have a `XML schema` for filling form given to me. I wanted to make my life easier by `exporting data` from excel to XML and then import it to filling form created in `PDF`. Everything works fine BUT... in filling form you can add multiple codes (Good description). If you choose multiple codes proper code to import data should like below, however excel says it is denormalized data.

Is it possible to do something about it in Excel?

```
<PurchaseInformation simplifiedInvoice="0">

  <SequenceNumber></SequenceNumber>
  <ReferenceNumber></ReferenceNumber>
  <IssuingDate></IssuingDate>

  <EUSupplier>

      <NameFree></NameFree>
      <AddressFree></AddressFree>
      <CountryCode></CountryCode>

      <EUTraderID>

          <VATIdentificationNumber issuedBy=""></VATIdentificationNumber>
          <TaxReferenceNumber issuedBy=""/>

      </EUTraderID>

  </EUSupplier>

  <GoodsDescription>

      <Code></Code>
      <SubCode></SubCode>
      <FreeText language=""/>

  </GoodsDescription>

  <GoodsDescription>

      <Code></Code>
      <SubCode></SubCode>
      <FreeText language=""/>

  </GoodsDescription>

  <Currency></Currency>
  <TransactionDescription>

      <TaxableAmount></TaxableAmount>
      <VATAmount></VATAmount>

  </TransactionDescription>

  <Deduction>

      <DeductibleVATAmount></DeductibleVATAmount>

  </Deduction>

</PurchaseInformation>
```

Comment: Is your problem that you cannot get the data back into Excel (as suggested by the question)? Or that you cannot get the data out of Excel (as suggested by the title)?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Cannot get it out of excel. "denormalized data" warning is shown by Excel. So I can impot everything to excel but cannot export it to XML properly.

Comment: Starting to think it is all about maxoccurs attribute, which prevents this xml schema from being exported.